# php mongo - cursor is not sorting dates properly

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code to query a mongo database for history data:

```
    function get_location_history($location)
    {
            global $m, $db;
            $collection = $db->location_ppg_history;
            try{
                    $query = array('tname'=>$location);
                    $cursor = $collection->find($query)->sort(['ppg_run_date'=>-1]);
                    return $cursor;
            } catch(MongoCursorException $e) {
                    return false;
            }
    }
```

This is the call to the above method ... and the logic to parse the results:

```
  $status = get_location_history($tname);   
  foreach ($status as $id=>$value) {
     ..... echo ("<td>".$value['ppg_run_date']."</td>");
  }
```

The output on the page looks like this: (just a subset of output to give you an idea)

```
    September 27 2016 16:08:47  
    September 19 2016 9:31:40   
    September 12 2016 9:23:43   
    September 05 2016 9:34:44   
    October 10 2016 9:35:33 
    October 03 2016 9:41:54
```

Within each month, as you can see, it's printing the dates in descending order, which is what I want.. But I can't figure out why September data is returned before October.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1**

This is what my data in the database looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b2283aea89161b704c8980"),
    "tname" : "t144f",
    "ppg_run_date" : "August 15 2016 15:16:17",
    "ppg_log_date" : "August 15 2016 20:38:17",
    "type" : "locstatus",
    "customized" : true
}
```

**EDIT 2**

This is the PHP code that creates the date field...

```
  $GLOBALS['gstrPPGRunDate'] = date('F d Y G:i:s', strtotime($matches[2]) );
```

Eventually, this Global variable is inserted into an array of data ($status) that represents an individual document.  That document in turn is added to the mongo collection.

```
try {
        $cursor = $collection->update(array('sdomain'=>$status['sdomain']) , array('$set'=>$status), array('upsert'=>true) );

        return true;
    } catch(MongoCursorException $e) {            
        return false;
    }
```

How do I change this to ensure that this field is treated as a mongo date instead of a string? I think I will try this:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php  to replace the logic that currently creates the global variable.

Comment: It might be to do with the format that the ppg_run_date field uses. Can you show us an example of your data, to help figure it out?

Comment: @VinceBowdren please see my Edit 1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your data; you're not storing *dates*, you're storing *strings*. So when they come to be sorted, it sorts them as strings - in *alphabetical order*.

I recommend you change the way your data is stored, so you store actual dates, something like this:

```json
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("57b2283aea89161b704c8980"),
  "tname" : "t144f",
  "ppg_run_date" : ISODate("2016-08-15T15:16:17.000Z"),
  "ppg_log_date" : ISODate("2016-08-15T20:38:17.000Z"),
  "type" : "locstatus",
  "customized" : true
}
```

Comment: @Happydevdays if you're using the php `date()' function to generate the ppg_run_date value, then yes you're getting a string. I don't know the php side of things very well, but a quick search suggests the [UTCDateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php) as a possibility.